# Fortran preprocessing with Portland compiler

Tags: preprocessor, fortran

I am trying to pre-process a Fortran module (pmu.F90) with pgf90. The module is as follows:

```
module pmu

   module variables

contains

   include 'file.F90'

end module
```

`file.F90` is a subroutine which contains the following lines:

```
 #ifdef PART  

    startm1 = xstart - 1

    startm2 = xstart - 2

    endp1   = xend + 1

    endp2   = xend + 2 

 #else    

    startm1 = xstart - 1

    startm2 = xstart - 1

    endp1   = xend + 1

    endp2   = xend + 1 

 #endif
```

If I compile with:

```
pgf90  -DPART    -Mfree -Mbounds -Msave -Mdclchk -r8 -Mpreprocess  -I/data/users/mrosso/fftw3/include    -c pmu.F90
```

I get

```
PGF90-S-0021-Label field of continuation line is not blank.
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the included file contains no procedures, which is what you need between the "contains" and "end module" statements in the module pmu file.

Another issue with using CPP with Fortran is that the Fortran include statement is not the same as the CPP #include. In particular, their interaction is not specified. That is, if you're including a file which itself contains CPP directives, it's one less thing that can go wrong if you use #include instead.

Comment: The OP stated that 'file.F90' holds a subroutine. If I understand it correctly, the piece of code he showed is just a part of it, not the entire thing. I agree with you on the point you made about the interaction between CPP and the Fortran include statement.